# Entity Framework 4 / Devart - ORA-00904 : invalid identifier

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, devart

Our intranet site stopped working over night. A short look into the errorlog showed me a

```
EntityCommandExecutionException - An error occurred while executing the command
```

with the inner exception

```
Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException - {"ORA-00904: \"MONTH\": invalid identifier"}
```

The exception occurs during a selection with LINQ. The where statement simply compares `DateTime`'s `Month` and `Year` against some integer.

The oracle table itself simply has 4 columns (`number:id PRIMARY KEY, varchar2:text, number:sum, date: creationdate`).

I can reproduce the problem local with a new devart model and with a ADO.NET entity model as well against the same database.

The environment:

- Devart dotConnect for oracle 6.10.96.0

Comment: ORA-00904 is raised when you're referencing an invalid column name; either it doesn't exist doesn't conform to Oracle's naming guidelines or is a reserved word. What are you executing that raises this error?

Comment: As I said the problem occurs over night. Yesterday everything was fine. But this morning the exception got raised. But absolutely nothing changed. Neither the framework or assemblies nor the oracle client. The column is a date with name anlagedatum(creationdate in german). I don't think this is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your .NET Framework version.

.NET v4.5 is supported by dotConnect for Oracle starting from the 7.2.77 version: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/revision_history.html .

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar type of problem in one of the project where database first and entity framework used. I found that the model file's attribute is different from database table field. When the field were made similar, it worked without any problem. Please check if the model and database table are similar in which "MONTH" is located. I hope it helps.